# Mysql join returns multiple rows but php foreach need single record

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreach

I have a simple join query :

```
select s.id, s.account_id, s.startdate, ss.skill_id, sk.skill_name 
from shyfts s 
   join shyfts_skills ss on ss.shyft_id = s.id 
   join skills sk on sk.id=ss.skill_id
```

This give me the results I expected

```
id      account_id  startdate   skill_id    skill_name
19783   35          2018-10-10  68          Delivery
19783   35          2018-10-10  67          Cooking
28766   76          2018-10-18  68          Delivery
```

The problem I have is I need to do a loop (foreach in php) but I only need to show unique shift so by ID. As you can see the shift id 19783 is a duplicate. Of course, I can do a GROUP BY but there will be one skill missing (Cooking).

I can do it by adding another select within the foreach-loop but it take too much performance on 200+ rows.

Or, maybe something like "if current $row['id'] is different than the previous $row['id'] but this is bad coding I think.

How can I do that ??

Comment: You can use `group_concat()`

Comment: If the query give you the result you want  ... what result you want to display on php?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `GROUP_CONCAT(fieldName SEPARATOR ',')` this function, you may concat just one field, and ofc. use GROUP BY.
That could be like [mysql join with multiple values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609753/mysql-join-with-multiple-values-in-one-column) this one question

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use select distinct statement for not show duplicates..

```
select distinct s.id, s.account_id, s.startdate, ss.skill_id, sk.skill_name 
from shyfts s 
   join shyfts_skills ss on ss.shyft_id = s.id 
   join skills sk on sk.id=ss.skill_id
```